# Analyticity at infinity: Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series, analytic-functions

Suppose that the series $$A_0 + A_1(z-z_0)^{-1} + \cdots + A_n (z-z_0)^{-n}+ \cdots$$ converges to $f(z)$ for all $z$ such that $r<|z-z_0|<\infty$ and let $f^*(\xi)=f(1/\xi), f^*(0)=A_0$. Show that $f^*$ is analytic at $\xi=0$.
The hint I have is that if $z_0 \neq0$ consider  the series $$f^*(\xi)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n \left( \frac{\xi}{1- \xi z_0} \right)^n$$
where $|\xi|<min \lbrace r,|z_0|^{-1} \rbrace$.
I don't know how to use the above to prove that $f$ is analytic at $\infty$. Any hint can be useful.
Thanks.

Comment: Compare with $\sum A_n\xi^{n}$  and show that $f^{*}(\xi) \to A_0$ as $\xi \to 0$.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thank you. @KaviRamaMurthy